# PostgreSQL directories explained

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I almost 'randomly' dig into some of the classical [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) installation folders on Ubuntu 22.04.1 and I was naively wondering what *exactly* are the following different postgres directories intended for, on a high level? (please notice that I may have missed some others)

- `/var/lib/postgresql/14/main`

which has super restrictive access, owned by the `postgres` user:

```sh
$ ls -l /var/lib/postgresql/14/main
ls: cannot open directory '/var/lib/postgresql/14/main': Permission denied

$ sudo ls -l /var/lib/postgresql/14/main
total 84
drwx------ 7 postgres postgres 4096 dec 14 13:04 base
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres 4096 jan 20 09:54 global
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres 4096 jan  1  2022 pg_commit_ts
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres 4096 jan  1  2022 pg_dynshmem
drwx------ 4 postgres postgres 4096 jan 20 09:58 pg_logical
drwx------ 4 postgres postgres 4096 jan  1  2022 pg_multixact
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres 4096 jan  1  2022 pg_notify
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres 4096 jan  1  2022 pg_replslot
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres 4096 jan  1  2022 pg_serial
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres 4096 jan  1  2022 pg_snapshots
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres 4096 jan 20 09:53 pg_stat
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres 4096 jan  1  2022 pg_stat_tmp
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres 4096 jan  1  2022 pg_subtrans
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres 4096 jan  1  2022 pg_tblspc
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres 4096 jan  1  2022 pg_twophase
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres    3 jan  1  2022 PG_VERSION
drwx------ 3 postgres postgres 4096 nov 27 00:59 pg_wal
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres 4096 jan  1  2022 pg_xact
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres   88 jan  1  2022 postgresql.auto.conf
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres  130 jan 20 09:53 postmaster.opts
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres  112 jan 20 09:53 postmaster.pid
```

- `/etc/postgresql/14/main/` *

which has less restrictive access, owned by the `postgres` user:

```sh
$ ls -l /etc/postgresql/14/main/
total 60
drwxr-xr-x 2 postgres postgres  4096 jan  1  2022 conf.d
-rw-r--r-- 1 postgres postgres   315 jan  1  2022 environment
-rw-r--r-- 1 postgres postgres   143 jan  1  2022 pg_ctl.conf
-rw-r----- 1 postgres postgres  5158 feb  3  2022 pg_hba.conf
-rw-r----- 1 postgres postgres  1636 jan  1  2022 pg_ident.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 postgres postgres 29141 jan  5 19:12 postgresql.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 postgres postgres   317 jan  1  2022 start.conf
```

- `/usr/share/postgresql/14/`

which has less restrictive access, curiously owned by the `root` user:

```sh
$ ls -l /usr/share/postgresql/14/
total 1388
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     10 nov  8 11:12 catalog_version
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 jan 20 09:53 contrib
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  33337 nov  8 11:12 errcodes.txt
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 106494 jan 20 09:53 extension
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 114638 nov  8 11:12 information_schema.sql
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   4096 jan  1  2022 man
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4703 nov  8 11:12 pg_hba.conf.sample
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1636 nov  8 11:12 pg_ident.conf.sample
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    640 nov  8 11:12 pg_service.conf.sample
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 917461 nov  8 11:12 postgres.bki
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  28825 nov  8 11:12 postgresql.conf.sample
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    278 nov  8 11:12 psqlrc.sample
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  44176 nov  8 11:12 snowball_create.sql
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  35224 nov  8 11:12 sql_features.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8430 nov  8 11:12 system_constraints.sql
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  22427 nov  8 11:12 system_functions.sql
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  47570 nov  8 11:12 system_views.sql
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 jan 20 09:53 timezonesets
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 jan 20 09:53 tsearch_data
```

I found [this](https://%60https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-file-layout.html) page, but it tells ab/etc/postgresql/14/main/out a `/var/lib/pgsql/data` folder, which I don't have on my system:

```sh
$ ls -l  /var/lib/pgsql/data
ls: cannot access '/var/lib/pgsql/data': No such file or directory
```

* Also, `/etc/postgresql/14/main/` is apparently the one and only folder reported by:

```sh
$ sudo -u postgres psql -c 'SHOW config_file'
               config_file               
-----------------------------------------
 /etc/postgresql/14/main/postgresql.conf
(1 row)
```

Comment: The data directory is obviously `/var/lib/postgresql/14/main/` in your machine. The location differs, depending on the installer which depends on the OS flavour (Ubuntu, RedHat, Centos, etc). In Ubuntu, the installations are usually under `/var/lib/postgresql/`. And note that you can have multiple instances of the same or different Postgres versions.

Comment: If you install another instance, say version 12, the data dir will be `/var/lib/postgresql/12/main`. If you install another instance of version 14, you'll have to use a different name for it (not "main"), say "second" and the data dir will be accordingly `/var/lib/postgresql/14/second/`

Answer (score 4):

The contents of the data directory [are documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-file-layout.html):

> | Item | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | `PG_VERSION` | A file containing the major version number of PostgreSQL |
> | `base` | Subdirectory containing per-database subdirectories |
> | `current_logfiles` | File recording the log file(s) currently written to by the logging collector |
> | `global` | Subdirectory containing cluster-wide tables, such as `pg_database` |
> | `pg_commit_ts` | Subdirectory containing transaction commit timestamp data |
> | `pg_dynshmem` | Subdirectory containing files used by the dynamic shared memory subsystem |
> | `pg_logical` | Subdirectory containing status data for logical decoding |
> | `pg_multixact` | Subdirectory containing multitransaction status data (used for shared row locks) |
> | `pg_notify` | Subdirectory containing LISTEN/NOTIFY status data |
> | `pg_replslot` | Subdirectory containing replication slot data |
> | `pg_serial` | Subdirectory containing information about committed serializable transactions |
> | `pg_snapshots` | Subdirectory containing exported snapshots |
> | `pg_stat` | Subdirectory containing permanent files for the statistics subsystem |
> | `pg_stat_tmp` | Subdirectory containing temporary files for the statistics subsystem |
> | `pg_subtrans` | Subdirectory containing subtransaction status data |
> | `pg_tblspc` | Subdirectory containing symbolic links to tablespaces |
> | `pg_twophase` | Subdirectory containing state files for prepared transactions |
> | `pg_wal` | Subdirectory containing WAL (Write Ahead Log) files |
> | `pg_xact` | Subdirectory containing transaction commit status data |
> | `postgresql.auto.conf` | A file used for storing configuration parameters that are set by `ALTER SYSTEM` |
> | `postmaster.opts` | A file recording the command-line options the server was last started with |
> | `postmaster.pid` | A lock file recording the current postmaster process ID (PID), cluster data directory path, postmaster start timestamp, port number, Unix-domain socket directory path (could be empty), first valid listen_address (IP address or `*`, or empty if not listening on TCP), and shared memory segment ID (this file is not present after server shutdown) |

The config files that you keep in a different directory are also documented: [`postgresql.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/config-setting.html#CONFIG-SETTING-CONFIGURATION-FILE), [`pg_hba.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) and [`pg_ident.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-username-maps.html). The other files are artifacts of your packager and not part of PostgreSQL.

The share directory is something different. It is not part of the database data, but of the software. The rest is probably in `/usr/lib/postgresql/14/` on your system.

Note that the directories where these data are are not fixed, and other packagers on other Linux distributions or other operating systems might choose different paths.

Comment: For Ubuntu, I think this page is a good place to start, if one wants to dig further or manage multiple instances/versions: https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/06/24/managing-multiple-postgresql-instances-on-ubuntu-debian/

Comment: Another good resource is: https://www.interdb.jp/pg/pgsql01.html